# PHP - Get dynamic values from keys from array and put into a list

Tags: php, arrays, api, imdb

I am working on a movie review site but I am stuck at an array problem. How can I get multiple values from an Array of writers?

I get a response like this from the API `Array ( [0] => Array ( [nconst] => nm0604555 [name] => Chris Morgan [attr] => (written by) ) [1] => Array ( [nconst] => nm0860155 [name] => Gary Scott Thompson [attr] => (characters) ) )`

I tried `echo $array[0]['name'];` but it only gives me the first value `Chris Morgan` because of the `[0]`

Also the array response keys varies depending on how many actors are in a film.

So what can I do to list the Writers in a list? Like this: `Chris Morgan, Gary Scott Thompson`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With my solution, you will not have a , after the last element :

```
 $actors= array();
    foreach ($array as $movie) {
        $actors[] = $movie['name'];
    }

    echo implode(',', $actors);
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic loop can handle this:

```
foreach ($array as $movie) {
    echo $movie['name'] . ",";
}
```

Comment: Deleting my answer looks like mine is almost duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

Array_walk;

```
   Array_walk($array,function($key,$val){
      echo $val['name']. ', ';
    });
```